# C++ segfault before main function executes

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm just learning c++. and I was trying to write a function that performed a sequence of operations on an array. The main thing that I find bizarre is that my code segfaults before the main function even executes. How can this be?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define ARRAY_SIZE(array) (sizeof((array))/sizeof((array[0])))

void SelectionSort(int num[]){
  int i, j, first, temp;
  int numLength = ARRAY_SIZE(num);
  for (i = numLength - 1; i > 0; i--){
    first = 0;  // initialize to subscript of first element
    for (j=1; j<=i; j++){   // locate smallest between positions 1 and i.
      if (num[j] < num[first])
        first = j;
    }
    temp = num[first];   // Swap smallest found with element in position i.
    num[first] = num[i];
    num[i] = temp;
  }
  return;
}

int* reverse(int arr[]){
  int temp[ARRAY_SIZE(arr)];
  for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(arr); i++){
    for(int j = ARRAY_SIZE(arr); i > -1; i++){
      temp[i] = arr[j];
    }
  }
  delete arr;
  return temp;
}

int* sequence(int arr[], int size){
  if(int size = 0){
    int r[1];
    r[0] = 1;
    return r;
  }
  else{
    int* r;
    r = reverse(arr);
    int next[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(arr); i++){
      next[i] = r[i] + arr[i];
    }
    SelectionSort(next);
    int ans[size + 1];
    ans[0] = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < ARRAY_SIZE(arr); i++){
      ans[i] = next[i - 1];
    }
    return ans;
  }
}


int main(void){
  cout << "Start ";
  int arr[1];
  int* print;
  for(int i = 0; i <= 20; i++){
    cout << "in loop";
    if(i = 0){
      int arr[1];
      print = sequence(print, i);
    }
    else{
      print = sequence(print, i);;
    }
    cout << "[ ";
    for(int j = 0; j <= ARRAY_SIZE(print); j++){
      cout << print[j] << ", ";
    }
    cout << " ]\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: You going out of bounds here: `for(int j = 0; j <= ARRAY_SIZE(print); j++){` it should be `for(int j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE(print); j++){`

Comment: Although print is a pointer not an array so ARRAY_SIZE() will not be correct.

Comment: Thanks, but it still segfaults before it even prints out anything in the main function. How does that work?

Comment: All of those lines where you're declaring an array with a variable number of items is not standard C++.  Things like this: `int ans[size + 1];`  If you really want a dynamic array, use `std::vector<int>`.  Not only will it be standard, you don't get into the mess of using a macro to determine the number of entries in an array (which doesn't work if you pass it to a function).  The reason is that a vector knows its size due to the `vector::size()` member function.

Comment: Yes, this is the exact code I am using, except that I fixed the last for loop to  for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){

Comment: You don't flush the stdout so it can segfult after `cout << "Start ";` and still not print anything.

Comment: Sidenote: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/NhA0RXSz/, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112156/selection-sort-in-c etc => does the same but no more raw pointers/macros/arrays/new/delete in your code, i.e. you'll be writing modern C++ instead of 'C in C++ dialect'

Comment: also #define ARRAY_SIZE(array) (sizeof((array))/sizeof((array[0]))) does not have any sense, because preprocessor doesn't know a thing about sizeof or array

Comment: Ah, OK. Again, thank you to everyone here, this is my first c++ program after learning a little c.

Comment: You can't use ARRAY_SIZE within your functions because `arr[]` is actually a pointer.

Comment: I assume you are not permitted to use std::vector() so you should read your text book on how to create a dynamic array in `c++`.

Comment: @MegaZeroX -- Take a step back and rewrite the code using `std::vector`.  Your current attempt will not work.  Arrays are stupid -- an array does not know its own size -- you have to figure it out by doing the sizeof() "trick".  In addition, passing an array only passes the address of the first entry -- all information about the array is lost, so using the macro `ARRAY_SIZE` in a function is meaningless and just adds to the bugs your code has.

Comment: @drescherjm - Well, if they were not permitted to use `std::vector`, why is the OP permitted to actually cheat by using something that isn't even C++, like variable arrays?  At least a `vector` is part of the C++ library -- what the OP is doing is not C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie of course array doesn't know it's size, but you and your code knows because array's size is fixed during compile time. It was very awkward when I understood this. If you use array, you don't need to get it's size, because you know it already

Comment: I don't think the OP realizes this is a cheat.

Comment: @strangeqargo -- Then you can't pass just an array as a parameter to some function without size information, and the OP is attempting to do that and believes they can somehow recover the size information.  That was my point.

Comment: To clarify, I am taking a C class, and the professor just gave us the very basic syntax required to compile a c++ program (he isn't a c++ programmer) and told us to do a single program in c++, before we write a shell in c. I don't think he is familiar with c++ at all, and I (and everyone else in this class) doesn't really understand anything about c++. I'm trying to figure out how to use vectors now.

Comment: @MegaZeroX Well, C and C++ are two different languages, so right there is an issue.  To use vectors, just `std::vector<int> ans(size + 1);` would have replaced the faulty line I pointed out earlier.  Then the rest of the code stays the same (with maybe a compile error that needs to be fixed).  In addition, returning an `int *` need not be done any more, since you can return a `std::vector<int>` by value.  In other words, instead of fighting with pointers, you will actually be on the way of solving the problem you're trying to solve, and it is implementing a selection sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run this code, I get output from main before a segfault occurs.

If you are relying on main's output to determine when the segfault occurs, you can get the segfault before any output is shown if the output buffer is never flushed. Output is not immediately shown on the screen when using cout but rather only when the output buffer gets flushed; if you use for example `cout << "Start " << endl;` instead of `cout << "Start ";`, the buffer will flush and you will see the output, since `endl` inserts a line-break and also flushes the buffer (and you probably want a line-break there).

In regards to finding your segfault, my initial guess from a very quick trace of your code suggests that a possibility may be because in your sequence function your check for size should be `if(size == 0)`, and NOT `if(int size = 0)`. Your size is being set to 0, rather than being checked for being equal to 0. The expression is interpreted as 0, which means false, so the else statement is being executed when you don't want that to happen. This may manifest itself as a problem resulting in a segfault later.
To avoid this, you should generally write your code a small piece at a time and compile and test often, so that you know where to fix your mistakes which will likely happen often (and is evident in multiple places here) while you are still learning.